# Calculate average value by hour of json data

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm having troubles with grouping samples by hour. Data structure looks like this:

```
data = [
    {
        "pressure": "1009.7",
        "timestamp": "2019-09-03 08:03:00"
    },
    {
        "pressure": "1009.7",
        "timestamp": "2019-09-03 08:18:00"
    },
    {
        "pressure": "1009.8",
        "timestamp": "2019-09-03 08:33:00"
    },
    {
        "pressure": "1009.8",
        "timestamp": "2019-09-03 08:56:00"
    },
    {
        "pressure": "1009.8",
        "timestamp": "2019-09-03 09:03:00"
    },
    {
        "pressure": "1009.8",
        "timestamp": "2019-09-03 09:18:00"
    },
    {
        "pressure": "1009.8",
        "timestamp": "2019-09-03 09:33:00"
    },
    {
        "pressure": "1009.7",
        "timestamp": "2019-09-03 09:56:00"
    },
    {
        "pressure": "1009.6",
        "timestamp": "2019-09-03 10:03:00"
    }
]
```

As you can see, there are 4 measurements of pressure every hour and I would like to calculate average value per hour. I've tried achieving this with Pandas, but no luck. What I've tried was to extract start and end timestamp, round them to full hour and then pass it to DataFrame as index, and json as data, but there's shape mismatch (no wonder). I thought that I would be able to pass it like this to df and later try to calculate mean, but it looks like there should me some intermediate step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your JSON mimics the above then we can pass it into a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    pressure            timestamp
0   1009.7  2019-09-03 08:03:00
1   1009.7  2019-09-03 08:18:00
2   1009.8  2019-09-03 08:33:00
3   1009.8  2019-09-03 08:56:00
4   1009.8  2019-09-03 09:03:00
5   1009.8  2019-09-03 09:18:00
6   1009.8  2019-09-03 09:33:00
7   1009.7  2019-09-03 09:56:00
8   1009.6  2019-09-03 10:03:00
```

---

then just group by the hour and take the mean of pressure.

```
hourly_avg = df.groupby(df['timestamp'].dt.hour)['pressure'].mean()
print(hourly_avg)
timestamp
8     1009.750
9     1009.775
10    1009.600
Name: pressure, dtype: float64
```

note, you'll need to make your date a proper DateTime and pressure into a floating-point value.

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['pressure'] = df['pressure'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem by creating a new dictionary with the date/hour as a key and the pressures as a list (the value of the dictionary).

```
d = {}

for _dict in data:
    key = _dict['timestamp'][:13] # 2019-09-03 08, etc.
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(float(_dict['pressure']))

for key, array in d.items():
    print(key, format(sum(array) / len(array), '.3f'))
```

Prints:

```
2019-09-03 08 1009.750
2019-09-03 09 1009.775
2019-09-03 10 1009.600
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
df['pressure'] = df['pressure'].astype(float)
df['hour'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour

pressure = df.groupby([df['hour']])['pressure'].mean()

print(pressure)
```

Output:

```
timestamp
8     1009.750
9     1009.775
10    1009.600
```